# How to create a logging system that shows the file name in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I create a logging system that shows the file name and the line number in right side.
In example, when I run

```js
console.log('Hello world');
```

in "index.js" that will log

```js
"Hello world                            (index.js:1)"
```

Comment: try taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272754/log-js-file-name-and-function-name/49273117). Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an error stacktrace to get the file and line number:

```js
function getFileLine(callee) {
    const orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
    Error.prepareStackTrace = (err, stack) => [stack[0].getFileName(), stack[0].getLineNumber()];
    const err = new Error();
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, callee);
    const lineNum = err.stack;
    Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
    return lineNum;
}

function logger(...args) {
    console.log(...args, `(${getFileLine(logger).join(":")})`);
}

logger("foobar");
```

If the filename provided is too long for your needs, then you can use `path.basename`:

```js
const path = require("path");

function getFileLine(callee) {
    const orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
    // there's a basename call here
    Error.prepareStackTrace = (err, stack) => [path.basename(stack[0].getFileName()), stack[0].getLineNumber()];
    const err = new Error();
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, callee);
    const lineNum = err.stack;
    Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
    return lineNum;
}

function logger(...args) {
    console.log(...args, `(${getFileLine(logger).join(":")})`);
}

logger("foobar");
```